# How can I set border and padding to the table rows?

Tags: html, css

I would like to add divisions and padding between rows, but I've noticed that row borders are displayed with `border-collapse: collapse`, but this removes the padding for the `<tr>` element. https://jsfiddle.net/c8ht9aso/

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 20px">
    <tr>
        <td>Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid blue; vertical-align: top; padding: 20px">
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid green; vertical-align: top; padding: 20px">
        <td>Another Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So I remove `border-collapse: collapse` and I can see the padding, but not the horizontal lines between rows: https://jsfiddle.net/0mecu52u/

```
<table style="border: 1px solid red; padding: 20px">
    <tr>
        <td>Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid blue; vertical-align: top; padding: 20px">
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-top:1px solid green; vertical-align: top; padding: 20px">
        <td>Another Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So how can I add a border and padding to a `<tr>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set both the `border` and `padding` in a table layout, it's better to set it on the `td` rather than the `tr`, that will make sure it to work across the browsers correctly.

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 20px;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Header</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Another Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```